# Sitecore how to get an ImageField full url, not a relative path?

Tags: media-library, urls

It's an Web API project, to provide some data for third parties.

```
var image = new MediaItem(imageField.MediaItem);
string src = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(image));
```

This only get a relative url like `"/en/-/media/myrestaurant/home-image-carousel-1.jpg"`

How can I get the full path of this iamge? something like `GetFriendlyUrl()` for a general link which I can get a full path of it as `https://local.xxrestaurant:443/en/about-us` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use MediaUrlOptions and to pass it to GetMediaUrl method.

You will have:

```
            var image = new MediaItem(imageField.MediaItem);
            MediaUrlOptions mediaUrlOptions = new MediaUrlOptions();
            mediaUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
            string src = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(image,mediaUrlOptions));
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps.